# Every second failed Data Explorer query just removes the last error

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, error-message

Start a new query. Put in something that is correct syntax. E.g.

```
SELECT NULL
```

Click `Run Query` and the correct results are displayed.

Make it a syntax error. E.g.

```
SELECT NULLx
```

Click `Run Query` and the correct error is displayed (and the previous results are not cleared).

Click `Run Query` again and the error is *cleared** (but the previous results remain).

Click `Run Query` again and the error is displayed again.

Correct the query so that it should display new results. E.g.

```
SELECT 1
```

Click `Run Query` and the previous error is cleared and the new results are displayed.

*The error cleared should be replaced by the new error. (Note you can change the query so that it should display a new error, e.g.

```
SELECT IN
```

and if there was an error displayed from the last query, this query will still just clear the error and leave the previous results.)

Comment: He's talking about the use of the SE [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), so this isn't a wayward SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Data Explorer is so incredibly responsive that your error was reported back to the browser before the fade out animation on the error box finished.

This left the error box in an incorrect state in cases where the error box was visible when you submitted something that would then subsequently return an error. If the animations are annoying, they can just be removed, but for right now I [created a fix](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=8f3c06dbb1a56e86c41421be34e070c8e1af9f1e) by making sure the animations are stopped irrespective of state before the new response is processed.

...Of course, that can lead to a situation where the error box remains when it shouldn't, which [I've now also addressed](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=5730aad39b80cac202a0f3601fbda31701544fa7).

Comment: I'll wait for this to go live before accepting it.

Comment: I've unaccepted this for the moment because the problem is effectively back again, at least in Chrome.

Comment: The form is a little different, but it is, yes. [Fixed already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126964/150235), but not deployed until I finish up some other stuff and get a chance to talk to waffles.

Comment: Yes, I saw it was probably fixed, but I thought I better flag it just in case :-)