# Data Explorer Error Messages Fade to Nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I was learning to use the Data Explorer (slowly), and had lots and lots of syntax errors.  As I rearranged bits and retyped bits to figure out my mistakes, I kept clicking the "Run Query" button without refreshing.  The first message was bright red text against a pink background, but each time I hit the "Run Query" button, the text and background would fade, getting paler and paler, and after 10 or 11 times, it's hard to tell that there's an error message at all, and very difficult to read.  Worse, I can't select it, so I can't even see it with the selection colors nor copy it into notepad.  The only workaround seems to be to to copy my query, refresh the entire page, and paste the query back in.  Obviously, this needs to not happen.

I am using Chrome 13.0.782.220 m on 32-bit Windows XP.

Comment: +1, reproduced in IE9 on Win7.  It looks like an `opacity` attribute is being added to the `error-message` div when you click the "Run Query" button and there's an error.  Then the opacity percentage gets smaller and smaller each successive click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, my fix to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119324/every-second-failed-data-explorer-query-just-removes-the-last-error) wasn't as effective as it should have been. jadarnel27 is correct in [his synopsis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126964/data-explorer-error-messages-fade-to-nothing#comment344592_126964) that the opacity isn't properly reset between successive error responses. I've had a fix for this for a while, but I evidently never committed it.

It is resolved in my local environment, so I'll push it out for waffles to grab later this evening.

**Update**: I've [pushed out a fix, now](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=b9b24ed8d4afd2f766dc7946fbb0c01aa8000c91) which just removes the fading nonsense outright. I might rework it later, but I need to tidy up some messes I've made with the JavaScript first.

Comment: Good to know that it was already addressed, and just an oversight on the commit.  (Also that I'm not going insane)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have been pulled yet. MSSQL noobs continue to suffer.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle It has not. I've got a whole slew of changes in the pipe, so batching them up before handing off to waffles. Will try and talk to him later in the week.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle Should be deployed now.